# how to show **** in textbox though it contains other text, in c#.net?

Tags: c#, webforms

i have a grid view with two fields id & password. i have added the update query where the password gets updated according to the id. but the problem is that to update the password , it must be shown in the grid view password field. so is there a way where i can show ***** instead of the actual text in that password field?

i just want to show stars instead of the actual paswrd in this gridview...is this possible? i have tried converting the field into a template and changing its display text ut that doesnt work...

i m doing this in .net  webforms..

Comment: Please specify your UI framework. WPF? Winforms? Webforms? Pure HTML?

Comment: i already mentioned that i m using .net framework & language is c#. sorry but i didn't understand UI framework but i m working on webforms

Comment: Webforms is your UI framework. It's a part of the .NET framework. So saying "I'm using C#/.NET" isn't enough for us to understand what you're writing. You can build a local non-web application using WPF, which would also be ".NET framework and C#". That's why we need the details.

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption that you're using WPF, you want the [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx) class; don't try and reinvent the wheel. Strictly that will display bullets rather than stars, but as that's what every other password field does in Windows, I'd suggest that's what you want to be doing.

(It is actually possible to change the character displayed by setting the [PasswordChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.passwordchar.aspx) property, but I still don't think you should be changing it to a star unless you've got a really good reason).

Comment: If you are using windows forms: System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextbox

Comment: @Philip Kendall    i think u didnt understand my questn.....i m not wanting to change from bullets to stars.. i want to change the display of characters to any symbol in the pswrd field...and i m using webforms

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="password"` to your password input field.